# AXIOS call giving Network Error in React-Native 0.63

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm trying to call API using common HTTPSERVICE method, Strangely I'm getting response whenever the debugger is connected, but API is throwing Network Error when debugger is not connected.

React-Native Version: 0.63.2
axios verison: 0.18.0

```js
const sendRequest = async (url, method, params, data={}, headers = {}) => {
  try {
    const options = {
      url,
      method,
      params,
      data,
      headers,
    }
    console.log(options);
    return await axios(options);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("request error",err);
    throw err;
  }
}

function* HttpService(url, methodType, params, data, headerParams = {}) {
  try {
    const user = yield select(state => state.ssoReducer.user);
    if (isTokenExpired(user.token)) {
      yield call(getPingFedToken);
    }
    const signIn = yield select(state => state.ssoReducer);
    const authToken = signIn.user?.token;
    const headers = {
      Authorization: `${authToken}`,
      'SWAP-MOBILE-APP': true,
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      ...headerParams
    };
    return yield call(sendRequest, url, methodType, params,  data , headers)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("http error",error);
    if (error.response.status === (403)) {
      yield put({
        type: SSO_FAILURE,
        payload: "Unauthorised alert"
      });
    }
    throw error;
  }
}

export default HttpService;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z5yA.png)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the problem is not in this part of the code.
I am suspecting the way you create `headerParams`.

here is what you need to do.

- check all the global methods that you are using in this flow ex. `URLSearchParams`
- make sure that they exist in the `web component` layer that is part of the JS engine related to the react-native version you are using.

**why:**

because, when you connect the debugger; you are not executing your JS code in the engine of React Native, but inside the one in the `chrome` you are debugging with.

this is a known issue in the react-native world, and to avoid it I suggest you use another debugger like https://infinite.red/reactotron

Comment: Tried installing reatcotron, api's were still fialing. We changed our url to http instead of https and it started working! not sure why https is not working. any thoughts?